# javascript selectIndex right value

Tags: javascript, select

I have two possible dropdown list that I'm working with. The first one looks like:

```
<select id="drop1" name="drop1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  ...
</select>
<input type="text" value="1" onclick="set(this.value);" />
```

and the second one looks like

```
<select id="drop2" name="drop2">
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  ...
</select>
<input type="text" value="1" onclick="set(this.value);" />
```

How can I make sure that if the value chosen in `set(this.value)` is  = 1 (January) for instance, I will end up selecting January and not -- neither Feb.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Welcome to SO. Can you be a little more elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Your'll need to iterate over the options of your `<select>` until you find one whose `value` is 1:

```
function selectOptionWithValue(select, value) {
    value = "" + value;
    var options = select.options;
    for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (options[i].value == value) {
            select.selectedIndex = i;
            return;
        }
    }
}

<input type="text" value="1"
  onclick="selectOptionWithValue(document.getElementById('drop1'), this.value);">
```